# Why does string.format("{0:-10}") give off different results on different PCs

Tags: c#, string

I have a line of code in my application that writes some string values to an XmlElement and applies some padding using string formating.

```
string.Format("{0:-10}{1:-10}{2:-10}", i.Department, i.Category, i.Item)
```

The outcome for this should be a 30 character string with the Department, Category and Item values.

So this works on our server but not on my local machine. What would cause this to stop working?

Comment: What is it displaying in your local PC? Are the regional settings different? What are Department, Category and Item? Plain strings?

Comment: can you post the expected and the observed output?

Comment: Your format string is wrong; in order to specify padding you use `,`, not `:`, so I assume you meant `"{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-10}"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use , instead of : - that's the correct syntax:

```
string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-10}", i.Department, i.Category, i.Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

These ways will work safely in any environment.

```
string.Format("{0}:-10{1}:-10{2}:-10", i.Department, i.Category, i.Item, ":-")
```

OR

```
string.Format("{0}{3}{1}{3}{2}{3}", i.Department, i.Category, i.Item, ":-10")
```

If you are going to do padding do as below. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) for more details on padding formats.

```
string.Format("{0}{3,-10}{1}{3,-10}{2} {3,-10}", i.Department, i.Category, i.Item, ":")
```